# Testing the performance of NICs in Amazon EC2

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, virtual-machine, nic

Is there any way to know any information about the Network Interface Cards (NIC) of servers in EC2?
I've tried a lot of commands that typically work in Linux, but seems it's all abstracted out when you try them on EC2 VMs.

Alternately, is there any way to characterize the performance of a NIC on a physical server that is hosting my VM (eg, to measure max throughput)? I was thinking there should be some tools for testing such things on a single server but I couldn't find any! (tools like iperf measure the bandwidth between two machines).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure testing the throughput of a nic would do much good since it seems to be variable. There is no official documentation on the subject. If you are service static content, S3 is your best bet. Otherwise use some sort of caching with varnish or something similar that you can scale out incase you are running into bandwidth issues.